# How to prove $ X $ is $ T_{2} $ iff for all $ x\in X $, $ \bigcap_{U\in \eta (x)}\overline{U}=\{x\} $

Tags: general-topology

Let $ (X,\tau) $ be a topological space. I am trying to prove the following statement.

> $ X $ is $ T_{2} $ if and only if for all $ x\in X $, $ \bigcap_{U\in \eta (x)}\overline{U}=\{x\} $.

My definition for a $ T_{2} $ space is as follows.

> A topological space $ (X,\tau) $ is said to be $ T_{2} $ if for all distinct $ x,y\in X $, there exists $ U\in \eta (x) $ and $ V\in \eta (y) $ such that $ U\cap V=\varnothing $ where $ \eta (x) $ is the set of all nhd of $ x $ and $ \eta (y) $ is the set of all nhd of $ y $.

Could you please give me a help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$ (\Rightarrow ) $; Suppose $ X $ is $ T_{2} $ (Hausdorff). Let $ x\in X $. Choose $ y\in X $ such that $ x\neq y $. Then there exist $ U_{x}\in \eta (x) $ and $ V_{y}\in \eta (y) $ such that $ U_{x}\cap V_{y}=\varnothing $. So $ y\notin \overline{U_{x}} $. Hence $ y\notin \bigcap_{U\in \eta (x)}\overline{U} $. So we have $ \bigcap_{U\in \eta (x)}\overline{U}=\{x\} $. Also if there is no $ y\in X $ such that $ x\neq y $ then $ X=\{x\} $ and hence obviously $ \bigcap_{U\in \eta (x)}\overline{U}=\{x\} $.

$ (\Leftarrow ) $; Now conversely suppose for all $ x\in X $, $ \bigcap_{U\in \eta (x)}\overline{U}=\{x\} $. Since $ \bigcap_{U\in \eta (x)}\overline{U}=\{x\} $ there exists $ U_{x}\in \eta (x) $ such that $ y\notin \overline{U_{x}} $. Hence $ X\setminus \overline{U_{x}}\in \eta (y) $ and $ U_{x}\cap (X\setminus \overline{U_{x}})=\varnothing $. Thus $ X $ is $ T_{2} $ (Hausdorff).